# is it valid to take an inverse of boths sides of a matrix equation?

Tags: matrices, inverse

say I want to solve for $Y$

$$(Y+BC^T)^{-1} = A$$

taking inverse of both sides and then solving it for $Y$ yields to :

$$Y = A^{-1} - BC^{T}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those operations are valid.

We can apply the same operations on both sides of an equality.